# I have implemented JWT token security in spring boot code. how will I get jwt token anywhere in my code? need to save audit

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, token

I have implemented jwt security token in spring boot by refering jwt security impemented videos.
So after login I get generated jwt token, For further end points to hit I need to pass jwt token from request header then re request will get authorize at dofilter() method in JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter class as shown below.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        String username = null;
        String authToken = null;
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String header = httpRequest.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            authToken = header.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(authToken);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
            }
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(authToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(httpRequest));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

But I need to get that jwt token anywhere i want in my code to get some data from token.
for example look below code

```
public static AuditDetails createAudit() {
        AuditDetails auditDetails = new AuditDetails();
        **auditDetails.setCreateUser(token.getUsername());**
        auditDetails.setCreateTime(new Date()); 
        return auditDetails;
    }
```

so basically i need to get username from token to same audit details, but how am i suppose get token in that code or anywhere in the code?

Comment: Hi. Have you considered using Spring Security all the way like shown here: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token is sent to your app via the `header (tokenHeader)`

**Edit**
If you do not want to use the content of your `HttpServletRequest` anywhere, you can use as per session, a value holder that you can `Inject` (autowire) in every service to utilize the submitted token. You can try the following

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyHolder {
    private String authToken;

    public String getAuthToken() {
        return authToken;
    }

    public void setAuthToken(String authToken) {
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }
}
```

Change the token value in your `JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter`

```
    @Autowired MyHolder myHolder;
    
    // ...

    String authToken = null;
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String header = httpRequest.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);
    if (header != null && header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        authToken = header.substring(7); // Here is your token
        
        // UPDATE THE TOKEN VALUE IN YOUR HOLDER HERE
        myHolder.setAuthToken(authToken);

        // ... 
    }
```

Access the token anywhere in your app by autowiring the MyHolder class

```
@Autowired MyHolder myHolder;

// ...
var token = myHolder.getAuthToken();
```

Comment: If you are suggesting above solustion,
My code structure is controller >> service >> commonService >> dao
So if suppose i am using your suggestion then i need to carry "ServletRequest request" from controller to dao in every end point